# How do I do multi field input

Tags: python, forms, django-models

Hello pros pardon my maybe stupid question but i was wondering how to do something like this in a django model.
Say I have 3 fields in a models name, quantity and price and a customer buys 3 items with different name quantity and price. lets say mango 2 $1, orange 5 $2, mango 2 $1 how do i do this in a model.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it. Made 2 models and used foreign key to relate to the. Used tabular admin and inline admin so I can edit and add more fields